# Integral non-injective substitution ($u=x^2+1$)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate:

$$\int x^3 \sqrt{x^2+1} dx$$

My solution:

> Choose $u=x^2+1 \Leftrightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{u-1}$, then du = $2x dx$. Therefore: $$\frac{1}{2} \int (u-1)(u)^{1/2} du = \frac{1}{2} \int (u^{3/2} - u^{1/2})du$$
>
> $$= \frac{1}{5} (x^2+1)^{5/2} - \frac{1}{3}(x^2+1)^{3/2} + C$$

This is what I did and I am wondering. Because $x =\pm \sqrt{u-1}$, how do I know which, plus or minus, should I use? I just assumed to use the positive one because the function is in a power of $2$.

Comment: hint :$$x=\sinh u \to  \sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{(\sinh u)^2+1}= \cosh u \\
\int (\sinh u )^3 \cosh u (\cosh u  du)$$

Comment: You didn't let $u = \pm \sqrt{x^2+1},$ you let $u = x^2+1$ and so solving for $x$ gave $\pm \sqrt{u-1}$

Comment: Typo. My solution is correct to the above person. I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Finding an antiderivative is, in most cases, a very informal procedure. In order to be more precise, the problem itself should specify a domain for the integrand and it does not. So pick whatever you want.

Comment: @GitGud Wouldn't the negative sign change the integral, or vice versa? Not this one because its in the power of 2 but like a different one

Comment: @user349557 It shouldn't, the minus sign would carry through with the derivative too, eventually canceling. In any case the theory behind the substitution is, I think, more enlightening than thinking about such examples. See, for instance, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definition). What you did is simply present two choices for $\phi$. There's no mention of $\phi$ being unique and you've probably seen a few examples where several substitutions work. This is another one.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Comment: If $u=x^2+1$, then $\text{d}u=2x\text{d}x$. Now, $$x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\cdot 2x\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}(u-1)\sqrt{u}\text{d}u$$ Notice that you don't even need to express $x$ in terms of $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recall what a $u$ substitution is really doing in an indefinite integral. You are replacing $$\int f(x)dx $$ with $$ \int f(x(u))x'(u)du$$ and noting that if $\frac{d}{du}F(x(u)) = f(x(u))x'(u)$ then $F'(x) =f(x).$ In other words finding an anti-derivative for $f(x(u))x'(u)$ is the same as finding one for $f(x).$

Let's take your example slowly. Say you have $x(u) = \sqrt{u-1}.$ Then you look for an antiderivative of $f(\sqrt{u-1})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-1}}.$ Say you pick $x(u) =-\sqrt{u-1}.$ Then you look for an antiderivative of $-f(-\sqrt{u-1})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-1}}.$ Yikes! These are different functions so their antiderivatives will probably be different!

But it all has to work out in the end. Why? This is just using two *different* u-substitutions. There's no need for $x(u)$ to be the same thing. In fact many integrals have two different $u$ substitutions that work for it.

So your example actually gets your question backwards. The real issue is what if you want to substitute $x(u)= u^2+1$, in other words you want to use a non-invertable $x(u).$

Then trouble will come at the stage where you've found an antiderivative $G(u)$ for $ f'(x(u))x'(u)$ and you want to express it as $F(x(u))$. You need to know whether to plug in $u = +\sqrt{x(u)+1}$ or $u = -\sqrt{x(u)+1}$ into $G(u)$ in order to get $G(u)$ into the form $F(x(u)).$

Let's take the simplest example I can think of: $$ \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}e^{\sqrt{x}}dx.$$ We'd be inclined to use $x(u) = u^2$ here, so let's look at $$f(x(u))x'(u) = \frac{1}{2u}e^{u}2u = e^u.$$ Pretty easy to find an antiderivative... just $e^u$ (that's why we chose this $u$ substitution).

Now here's the tricky part. Naively, we would normally sub back in $u = \sqrt{x}$ and write the answer as $e^{\sqrt{x}} + C.$ But $x = u^2$ also admits another solution $u=-\sqrt{x}$ so we might be feel equally entitled to write $e^{-\sqrt{x}}+C,$ which would be wrong.

The key is you need to write the antiderivative $e^u$ as $F(x(u)) = F(u^2).$ We see that $e^u=e^{\sqrt{u^2}}$ is a valid way to do this and $e^{-\sqrt{u^2}}$ is not. So everything checks out, provided we're careful.

Generally, this issue never crosses one's mind  because you write $u = \sqrt{x}$ at the outset, cause it's 'what you're subbing for' in the function. So you know which branch of the inverse of $x(u)=u^2$ you chose.

Let's see what happens if we are inclined to choose differently. Consider if we instead had $$ \int -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx.$$ What if we wanted to "sub in $u=-\sqrt{x}$?" What we're really doing then is, again, taking $x(u) = u^2$ and getting $f(x(u))x'(u) = - e^{-u},$ antidifferentiating to obtain $e^{-u}$ and then realizing that's $e^{-\sqrt{u^2}}$ so that the anti derivative is $e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ How does this gel with "subbing in $u=-\sqrt{x}$?"  The minus sign that we got from integrating $e^{-u}$ instead of $e^u$ canceled with the minus sign from "du = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx".

So there's actually no difference between subbing $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $u=-\sqrt{x}$ after all.

You can think of the 'u substitution ritual' as a convenient mnemonic for what's actually going on under the hood. (It doesn't help that it's completely backwards from what's going on, but it is much easier to use that way.)

Comment: Thx for writting all this